# Layout is called with express-partials even when layout:false

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In my `layout.ejs`, I use the variable `user` as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="user-info">username: <%= user.username %></div>
    <%- body %>
</body>
</html>
```

Each page requires the user to be logged in. However, the login page itself shouldn't require `req.user`, so I want to make a separate login page which doesn't (well, shouldn't) use the partial. I tried to do this as follows:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login.ejs', {layout: false});   
})
```

`login.ejs` only contains static markup. However, it still gives me errors about the lines that `layout.ejs` tries to access the `user` variable.

Is this a bug with `express-partials`? How can I avoid/fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you wrap the `user-info` div inside a `if` conditional to display the `username` only if the `user` object is defined?

Comment: @ArunKumar yes, that could solve the problem. But it's still curious why the layout is called here at all.

Comment: This might be silly. Did you restart the node process after adding `{layout: false}`?

Comment: Omg. I thought I did, but apparently I didn't. It's working now :D Thanks!

Comment: Ah! Do you want me to add that as an answer? :P Might be useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you did not restart `node` after adding `{layout: false}`. Try restarting the node process. That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

EJS provides conditionals, so you should apply it to your `layout.ejs` file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="user-info">username: <%= user.username %></div>
    <%if (user.username) { %>
         <%- body %>
    <% } %>
    <%- body %>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically this tells the template if the user.username exists, render this part, else don't render it.